# drupal 8 настройки видимости стали другими

Tags: drupal8

[image: Было так]

[image: Стало так]

НЕ знаю что, где не так нажал, но сначала было как на первом скрине, затем стало как на втором. Как вернуть все на место?

Answer (score 0):

Виноват был модуль rules 8.x-3.0-alpha6.
https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/releases/8.x-3.0-alpha6

После его удаления, все вернулось на место.